# WordPress wp_signon() succeeds but no cookie is attached to response header

Tags: wordpress, cookies, customization

I am troubleshooting a problem with a WordPress front-end user login form. The code works great with the same site on a development server, but not on the production server.

On the production server, the authentication passes, and the wp_signon() returns a full user object, however the cookie is not being inserted into the response stream.

The following code demonstrates this:

```
$user = wp_signon( '', $secure_cookie );
var_dump($user);
```

When using Fiddler to sniff the packets, this is what is returned by the production server:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Fri, 24 May 2013 07:53:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Pingback: http://www.domain.com/blog/xmlrpc.php
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: http://www.domain.com/log-in/
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Cacheable: YES:FORCED
X-Varnish: 1753703763
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-Cache: MISS
CF-RAY: 73868e9b8da0418
Content-Length: 802

object(WP_User)#329 (7) {
["data"]=>
object(stdClass)#388 (10) {
["ID"]=>
string(2) "53"
["user_login"]=>
string(14) "SubscriberTest"
["user_pass"]=>
string(34) "$P$B8O8w6awJnKrHNoFLOyHJHfKiPE1nt/"
["user_nicename"]=>
string(14) "subscribertest"
["user_email"]=>
string(33) "SubscriberTest@domain.com"
["user_url"]=>
string(0) ""
["user_registered"]=>
string(19) "2013-05-23 05:56:42"
["user_activation_key"]=>
string(0) ""
["user_status"]=>
string(1) "0"
["display_name"]=>
string(14) "SubscriberTest"
}
["ID"]=>
int(53)
["caps"]=>
array(1) {
["subscriber"]=>
bool(true)
}
["cap_key"]=>
string(15) "wp_capabilities"
["roles"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(10) "subscriber"
}
["allcaps"]=>
array(3) {
["read"]=>
bool(true)
["level_0"]=>
bool(true)
["subscriber"]=>
bool(true)
}
["filter"]=>
NULL
}
```

The WordPress control panel login still works and the cookie is inserted when signing into the backend.

The production server is also using CloudFlare, but I am not sure if that could be related or not. I have sent a support ticket to Cloud Flare as well, hoping that they can confirm whether their proxy service might be stripping them off.

Here is what the response header portion looks like on my development server when running the same code. In this one you can see that the cookie is being sent:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 24 May 2013 02:18:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.11
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Pingback: http://domain.com/blog/xmlrpc.php
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: wordpress_548d950a57c83d7fc5c2eb781062ef26=SubscriberTest%7C1369534704%7C08d4578ca9049beadffa39e0be0ea941; path=/blog/wp-content/plugins; httponly
Set-Cookie: wordpress_548d950a57c83d7fc5c2eb781062ef26=SubscriberTest%7C1369534704%7C08d4578ca9049beadffa39e0be0ea941; path=/blog/wp-admin; httponly
Set-Cookie: wordpress_logged_in_548d950a57c83d7fc5c2eb781062ef26=SubscriberTest%7C1369534704%7Cc41eb224ebec7f57982d0f93e70f7cff; path=/; httponly
Set-Cookie: wordpress_logged_in_548d950a57c83d7fc5c2eb781062ef26=SubscriberTest%7C1369534704%7Cc41eb224ebec7f57982d0f93e70f7cff; path=/blog/; httponly
Location: http://domain.com/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Hoping the morning crew might have some ideas.  I have been battling with this bugger for over a week now, and I really need to get it fixed today before leaving for the weekend.

 : (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered that Varnish was running on the production server and it was stripping off the cookies. Once URL exclusions were added, the WP functions started working as expected.